# C++ Adding to Linked Lists Which Include Char[] as a Parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, list, data-structures, linked-list

I'm working on a slightly different take on linked lists than I've tried to tackle before, and it's leading to some issues. I'm familiar with handling a linked list using simple integer parameters, but I'm trying to handle a character array, and can't figure out exactly how to add to a list in this situation:

```
struct process{
    pid_t pid;
    char userArgument[1024];
    struct process* next;
};

class processList{
    private:
    process *head, *tail;
    public:
    processList(){
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add(int pid, char argument[]){
        process *tmp = new process;
        tmp->pid = pid;
        tmp->userArgument = argument; //PROBLEM. I want this to take a character array passed to add() and use it as the userArgument for this new process
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }

    }
};
```

The intended behaviour of the add function would be to create a new process with a pid of type int, and a new userArgument of type char[]. In the line I've marked as the problem, however, it throws up an error, and I've tried alternative versions without success (passing add() a string instead, using c_str(), etc). I'm stuck trying to get this to work, and would appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: If you're using C++, is there some reason you're avoiding `std::string`?

Comment: std::string would likely have been a better decision and I realized that many hours after I started this project, but at this point the entire program is written around character arrays so I'm dedicated to that format.

Comment: @MMMMMCK - bad idea. When in hole - rule #1, stop digging.

Comment: @MMMMMCK _"... but at this point the entire program is written around character arrays ..."_ `std::string` supports c-style character arrays using the `c_str()` function pretty well. Also you always can interact using the `data()` function, if you need write access. Any more substantial reasons not to use it (besides homework assignment restrictions)?

Comment: No, mostly general inexperience. This is good insight, I'll take a look at some of these functions and see if I can incorporate them into my work, thank you.

Comment: @MMMMMCK I wrote an answer which should give you the idea. Please get rid of that _old school_ c-style stuff of handling strings.

Comment: @MMMMMCK To add up upon my answer: The [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) feature is available with the very latest standard ([tag:c++17]), and would give you even better performance in regards to avoid copying strings around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   strcpy(tmp->userArgument, argument);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, perfect, I completely forgot about strcpy and it worked instantly! Thanks for the help, will accept when possible.

Comment: _@Jim_ Not to mention that is prone to buffer overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assignable.

To copy an array, you must use a loop. Or use a function that does the loop. To figure out which function to use, you must first figure out what `argument` pointer is pointing at.

If `argument` points to a null terminated string that is guaranteed to be at most 1023 characters long, then you can use `std::strcpy`. If the length is not limited, then you need to figure out what to do in that case.

If `argument` points to an array of at least 1024 `char`, then you can use `std::memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
void add(int pid, char argument[])
    {
        process *tmp = new process;
        tmp->pid = pid;
        //tmp->userArgument = argument; //PROBLEM. I want this to take a character array passed to add() and use it as the userArgument for this new process
        size_t count = sizeof(tmp->userArgument);
        memcpy(tmp->userArgument,argument,count);
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
    {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: `memcopy` is an even worse idea than `strncpy()`. Are all people going mad here? What does this has to do with c++ programming?

Comment: The requestor is presumably using a fixed data block "char [1024] to store various data fields of interest - other than strings.  "memcpy" is the appropriate technique in that situation.

Comment: We can agree to disagree that `memcpy()` and using a _"fixed data block"_ is the appropriate technique in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this in c++ would be to use `std::string` (which supports direct assignment, whereas `char[]` array doesn't):

```
struct process{
    pid_t pid;
    std::string userArgument;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    struct process* next;
};

class processList{
    private:
    process *head, *tail;
    public:
    processList(){
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add(int pid, const std::sting& argument) {
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        process *tmp = new process;
        tmp->pid = pid;
        tmp->userArgument = argument; // Works just out of the box with std::string
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }

    }
};
```

You might consider adding functions that allow to access the c-style string from your `process` struct:

```
struct process{
    pid_t pid;
    std::string userArgument;
    struct process* next;

    // Convenience getter/setter functions to interact with c-style character arrays
    const char* userArgumentCStyleString() const {
        return userArgument.c_str();
    }
    void userArgumentCStyleString(const char* args) {
        userArgument = std::string(args);
    }    
};
```

This way you also get rid of that ugly fixed sized `char[1024]` array.

Comment: Not a good idea to do the extra copy into the parameter, and then again into the member. Better to either pass by reference, or move into the member. Edit: I see that was fixed while I was typing. Speaking of *modern c++ standards*, `std::string_view` might be a good choice for the argument.

Comment: @user2079303 Let's not _overstress_ the OP ;-). But yes, `std::string_view` would be the even better choice.

Comment: @user2079303 HTML tags like `<strike>` won't work with the restricted markdown in comments BTW.